# Is there a way in Python to create a user name and password menu where the username and password are validated through information in a .txt file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Still new to python, so say like the user id is correct and it matches user id with password it would  then allow user to access functionalities or generate error message and ask user to enter detail again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below shows an example of how to do such a thing.

```
# read in username/password data from users.txt
with open('users.txt', 'r') as f:
    users = f.read().splitlines()

# create key/value pairs in dictionary for username/password
logins = {}  # create empty dictionary
for user in users:  # one user at a time
    un = user.split(',')[0]  # get user name
    pw = user.split(',')[1]  # get password
    logins[un] = pw  # add to dictionary

# ask user for info
username = input("Enter username: ")
password = input("Enter password: ")

# keep asking if incorrect user name or incorrect password
while username not in logins.keys() or logins[username] != password:
    if username not in logins.keys():  # if username not in list
        print("Not in user list... Try again.")
    elif logins[username] != password:  # if password does not match
        print(f"Not the correct password for {username}... Try again.")
    # ask user for info again
    username = input("Enter username: ")
    password = input("Enter password: ")

print("Access granted!")
# rest of the program goes below here
```

The username and password information is stored in a text file called `users.txt`. This program assumes the following format:

```
user1,pass1
user2,pass2
user3,pass3
user4,pass4
```